# Delete Neo4j legacy node index with no name

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4j graph db with several legacy node indexes that I have upgraded to Neo4j 2.0.0. I am taking advantage of the new features in the latest version and so will be moving away from legacy indexes and ultimately deleting them. In preparation for this I noted that in my list of legacy indexes, there is one with no name. This is listed both through the legacy webadmin UI, the Neo4j shell via the index --indexes command, and the REST API. A cut down excerpt from the response to the REST API shows

Request::

```
GET http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/
```

Response:

```
{
  "": {
    "template": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node//{key}/{value}",
    "provider": "lucene",
    "type": "exact"
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no index title! Consequently I cannot seem to find a way to delete it. I have tried to delete it via the "indexes" tab in webadmin, the index commands in neo4j-shell and the REST API. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the "Indexes" tab of webadmin? There was the ability to delete one of the indexes.

Alternatively in the neo4j-shell, try

```
 eval db.index().forNodes("").delete();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Sorry I should have said I had tried the "Indexes" tab of webadmin (I have edited my question to make this clear). No joy there unfortunately. I shall try your second suggestion now.

Comment: OK, so no luck unfortunately. I get `(InvocationTargetException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EvaluatorEx ception: missing name after . operator (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown Source> at line number 1)`.